# How do I convert complex function to lambda in python?

Tags: python, lambda

I'm thinking of ways to convert a more complex function to lambda and put it inside a map instead of f. The function is this:

```
#this function should be in lambda
def f(s):
    if (type(s) == int):
        return s*2
    else:
        return s.replace('r', '*')

lst = [4,5,6,'rer', 'tr',50,60]
lst = list(map( f, lst))
#result of lst is [8, 10, 12, '*e*', 't*', 100, 120]
#lst = list(map ( lambda x.... , lst))
```

Or lambda is only supposed to deal with short functions? Big ones have to be 'decomposed' out into separate functions?

Answer (score 2):

Use `if` `else` statement in a `lambda`:

```
print(list(map(lambda x: x*2 if type(x)==int else x.replace('r','*'),lst)))
```

Output:

```
[8, 10, 12, '*e*', 't*', 100, 120]
```

Even better, use `isinstance`:

```
print(list(map(lambda x: x*2 if isinstance(x,int) else x.replace('r','*'),lst)))
```

Comment: perfect... is it possible to create arbitrarily long lambda functions?

Comment: @ERJAN What you mean?

Comment: how big can a lambda function be? it can be as complex and long as a separate function?

Comment: @ERJAN What makes you think there are limits to the "size" of a lambda?

Answer (score 1):

Prefer `isinstance` in place of `type`

```
lst = [4,5,6,'rer', 'tr',50,60]
lst = list(map(lambda x: x*2 if isinstance(x, int) else x.replace('r', '*'), lst))

lst
[8, 10, 12, '*e*', 't*', 100, 120]
```